# White spaces in report

Tags: line-breaking

My editor produces a new paragraph every time I omit a line with pressing 2 times enter. I would like to turn this function off and begin new paragraphs only with explicit `\par` command.

Does anybody knows how to do so? I am using TeXmaker (on Ubuntu).

Comment: You could try to replace (find & replace, just once as a last step before compile) every double line skip by a double line skip with a `%` in between. That way, you would still get the code spacing, just with `%` on a single line in between every "paragraph".

Comment: Oh, and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :) Note that we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts (I've edited your question to reflect that). While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Xavier the OP is not a new user...

Comment: @karlkoeller 3 days new still qualifies for a warm welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

You *could* do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{\endlinechar=`\ }

\begin{document}

Something here. After a blank line will there be a new paragraph? Here is a real par\par

Something here. After a blank line will there be a new paragraph?

Here is a real par.\par

And text after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that you know it's possible, don't do it. If you want to separate sentences, just write

```
A sentence.
%
Another one
```

but I don't see how both these approaches make your typescript more readable.

Comment: @HonzaZubáč In my opinion you make it *less* readable: a `\par` command is more difficult to spot than a blank line.

Comment: To make my raw typescript more readable I wanted to omit a line around equations without beginning a new paragraph (which actually produces unintenional white line in the output file) when mixing text and equations. Your code itself seems to work fine, but I haven't adapted it on my document yet (some problems with  inserted pictures).

Comment: @HonzaZubáč Please, don't do it. If you want to visually isolate displayed equations, put `\[` alone on one line, then the equation and on a line by itself the closing `\]`. If you want add also a `%` line. But use blank lines for separating paragraphs. Using `\par` makes your document unparseable.